# get exitcode of last executing function - difference between $? and $(echo "$?")?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I know that it is possible to get the exitcode from the last executed function in a sh script by assigning $? to a variable.
e.g. `_exitcode=$?`

However, I also saw another method which works like this: `_exitcode=$(echo "$?")`.

Does it make any difference?

Comment: $() runs whatever's inside within a subshell and then assigns the stdout to your variable.  $? is just the return code of the last run command.  The outcome will be the same in your case.

Comment: That's just a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) -- avoid that wasteful antipattern.

Comment: If there was an advantage, `_exitcode=$(echo $(echo "$?"))` would surely be better still?

Comment: `?` is a variable just like `_exitcode`..  why call a process to assign one variable to another?